# How to use ArrayLists to output (.txt file) a report in a specific format that lists scores of athletes?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I'm having a bit of trouble with this project, and would greatly appreciate some help.

Here's a link to it: 
http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/cse1223/currentsem/projects/CSE1223Project11.html

---

The basic gist is it's "A program that reads in a text file that uses a specific input format and uses it to produce a formatted report for output."

Specifically:
"For this lab you will write a Java program that produces a simple formatted report. The program will prompt the user to enter a file name. This file must contain information in a specific format (detailed below). Each "block" of the file contains information for one player in a competition -- the name of the player followed by a number of different scores that that player achieved. The program should find each player's average score, median score and best and worst scores and display them in a line on the final summary report. The program should also determine which player has the highest average score and which player has the lowest average score."

---

I get the following errors when I try and compile it:

```
Enter an input file name: Project11.txt 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException... -1 
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source) 
at Project11.getMedian(Project11.java:68) 
at Project11.main(Project11.java:27)
```

Sorry for not clarifying.

Line 68 is: return (inList.get(Middle - 1) + inList.get(Middle)) / 2;
Line 27 is: int median = getMedian(List);

Hope that helps.

---

Here's my code:

import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

```
public class Project11 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an input file name: ");
        String input = in.nextLine();
        File inputFile = new File(input);
        List<Integer> List = readNextSeries(inputFile);
        int median = getMedian(List);
        int mean = getAverage(List);
        int max = getMaximum(List);
        int min = getMinimum(List);
        System.out.print("Enter an output file name: ");
        String out = in.nextLine();
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(out);
        System.out.println("Median = " + median);
        System.out.println("Mean = " + mean);
        System.out.println("Max = " + max);
        System.out.println("Min = " + min);
        outputFile.println(median);
        outputFile.println(mean);
        outputFile.println(max);
        outputFile.println(min);
        outputFile.close();
    }  

    // Given a Scanner as input read in a list of integers one at a time     until a negative
    // value is read from the Scanner. Store these integers in an     ArrayList<Integer> and
    // return the ArrayList<Integer> to the calling program.

    private static List<Integer> readNextSeries(File f) {
        ArrayList<Integer> List = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        try {
            Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(f);
            while (fileScan.hasNextInt()) {
                int value = Integer.parseInt(fileScan.next());
                List.add(value);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return List;
    }

    // Given a List<Integer> of integers, compute the median of the list     and return it to
    // the calling program.

    private static int getMedian(List<Integer> inList) {
        int Middle = inList.size() / 2;
        if (inList.size() % 2 == 1) {
            return inList.get(Middle);
        } 
        else {
            return (inList.get(Middle - 1) + inList.get(Middle)) / 2;
        }
    }

    // Given a List<Integer> of integers, compute the average of the     list and return it to
    // the calling program.

    private static int getAverage(List<Integer> inList) {
        int total = 0;
        int average = 0;
        for(int element:inList){
            total += element;
        }
        average = total / inList.size();
        return average;
    }

    private static int getMaximum(List<Integer> inList) {
        int largest = inList.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < inList.size(); i++) {
            if (inList.get(i) > largest) {
                largest = inList.get(i);
            }  
        }
        return largest;
    }

    private static int getMinimum(List<Integer> inList) {
        int smallest = inList.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < inList.size(); i++) {
            if (inList.get(i) < smallest) {
                smallest = inList.get(i);
            }
        }
        return smallest;
    }
}
```

---

Thank you very much for any input.

Comment: Project11.java:68 - Project11.java:27 don't say "error is from 68 to 27".. it says: "the error is caused by getMedian which is called by main and more if present.." Post line 68 of Project11

Comment: Format your code better and point to us which lines have the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getMedian(...)` method doesn't handle the empty list case.  Say you have an empty list (list of size 0), what do you think will happen?  It will hit this line:

```
return (inList.get(Middle - 1) + inList.get(Middle)) / 2;
```

This `inList.get(Middle - 1)` is the same as `inList.get(0 - 1)` if the size of the list is 0.  You want to make sure you methods handle all different cases.  I'd recommend adding an if statement for this specific case (throw an Exception or give output so user knows what is wrong).

**NOTE**:  This "all cases handling" applies to all your methods.